# Can't get Bootstrap Modal to show each JSON record

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

The idea here is to click value from Select dropdown press submit and php retrieves records from MySQL saving to a **json encoded variable** where I use jQuery to access each record to display each one as a Modal for 30 seconds before the Modal shows the next record.

I have the form working, the php call to MySQL and I have the json variable with all the data. I have a bootstrap Modal, and it will show the header, but not the body of the record where I am trying to display only 2 of the fields - "name" and "description".  I can even see all the records in the modal body in the p element with `#name` id, when I click on inspect, but just won't go in the modal.

```
<?php
require_once('../admin/login.php');
$conn = login();

if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $query = ("select * from exercise where type = '$type'");
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  $row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercise.css">
    <title>Workout App</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Workout App</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline">
            <Select NAME="type" class="custom-select">
                <Option selected disabled>Choose exercise</Option>
                <Option VALUE="cardio">Cardio</Option>
                <Option VALUE="circuit">Circuit</Option>
                <Option VALUE="abs">Abs</Option>
                <Option VALUE="stretch">Stretch</Option>
            </Select>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
        <button id="restart" class="btn btn-primary">Restart</button>
        <button id="pause" class="btn btn-primary">Pause</button>
        <button id="start" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
        <div id="progress">
          <div id="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <?php 
            if(isset($row)){
              echo "<h2>".ucwords($type)."</h2>";
              echo "<button type='button' id='begin' class='btn btn-primary'>Begin</button><br>";
            }
        ?>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Exercise</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="name"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>    

    </div>    
<script>
$( "#begin" ).click(function() {
  var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
    $.each(jqueryarray, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            if (key == 'name' || key == 'description')
            $("#name").append(key + ": " + value + "<br>");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script src="exercise.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery works when appending the JSON to `#name` as shown below. The problem I am having is that the modal is not showing the data.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p id="name">name: standard crunch<br>
  description: arms behind head, interlocked thumbs support neck, chin off chest, eyes on ceiling, knees bent then raise head and chest off floor<br> 
  name: left side crunch<br>
  description: standard crunch with knees laid all the way over to the right side<br>
  name: right side crunch<br>
  description: standard crunch with knees laid all the way over to the left side<br>
  name: superman crunch<br>
  description: toe touches with legs straight in the air and body in l formation reach out with arms straight up to touch toes<br>
  </p>
</div>
```

here is the variable after parsing the JSON

```
var jqueryarray = [{"id":"22","name":"standard crunch","description":"arms behind head, interlocked thumbs support neck, chin off chest, eyes on ceiling, knees bent then raise head and chest off floor","type":"abs","group":"1"},{"id":"23","name":"left side crunch","description":"standard crunch with knees laid all the way over to the right side","type":"abs","group":"2"},{"id":"24","name":"right side crunch","description":"standard crunch with knees laid all the way over to the left side","type":"abs","group":"3"},{"id":"25","name":"elbows to knees","description":"crunch with palms over head almost like pulling your head forward trying to bring elbows to knees with legs crossed off the ground parallel to the ground","type":"abs","group":"4"},{"id":"26","name":"superman crunch","description":"toe touches with legs straight in the air and body in l formation reach out with arms straight up to touch toes","type":"abs","group":"5"},{"id":"27","name":"leg lifts","description":"hands under back with feet 6 inches off ground then raise and lower never dropping below the starting point","type":"abs","group":"6"},{"id":"28","name":"in and outs","description":"hands behind head, feet in leg lift position, raise head and chest off floor and keep it there, then pull knees in to chest","type":"abs","group":"7"},{"id":"29","name":"hip rock","description":"hands behind head, feet together, legs bent forming diamond, and lift hips off ground while keeping upper body off floor","type":"abs","group":"8"},{"id":"30","name":"bicycle","description":"hands behind head, feet off the ground, knees bent, bringing elbow cross body to knee and alternating, kicking out like bicycle","type":"abs","group":"9"},{"id":"31","name":"full body crunch","description":"elbows in air w palms by ears, thrusting forward so elbows end up by your side raising upper body while extended legs have been pulled and knees tucked up towards your chest","type":"abs","group":"10"}];
```

Adding Image to show the empty modal-body:
[image]

Comment: Since the PHP code is working, it might be better to just show the page source in your question. I put what I could into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wq3ppdo/1/), and it appears to work.

Comment: You were able to get the modal dialog pop-up box to populate with data?

Comment: Try clicking the the "Begin" button in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wq3ppdo/1/). That is what you expect, correct? Is there any chance there is styling that makes the `<p>` element hidden?

Comment: I see now that your jsfiddle does show it in the Modal.  How did you do that?

Comment: It's all your code in the jsfiddle, so it's your code that is doing it. Of course, the jsfiddle does not include `exercise.css` and `exercise.js`. The issue could be in one of those.

Comment: I took out those 2 files and it works now.  Thanks for helping me.